# setRepeating Not Working in Alarm Manager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, calendar, alarmmanager

I use the code below to start and stop service in android, first repeating alarm works, but second one fails most of the time. When I disable the first repeating  then second one works. What could be the problem?

```
public void startAlarm(Context context,int StartHour,int StartMin,int PauseHour,int PauseMin) {

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    Calendar firstTurn = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar secondTurn = Calendar.getInstance();

    // set times
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, TimerAlarmReciver.class);
    intent1.setAction("START");
    firstTurn.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, StartHour);
    firstTurn.set(Calendar.MINUTE, StartMin);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 15, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, TimerAlarmReciver.class);
    intent2.setAction("STOP");
    secondTurn.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, PauseHour);
    secondTurn.set(Calendar.MINUTE, PauseMin);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 16, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTurn.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, secondTurn.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new AlaramTask1(context,StartHour,StartMin).excute();

new AlaramTask2(context,PauseHour,PauseMin).excute();
```

you can perform main logic on **`onPostExecute`**